# Two empty strings are not equal in Javascript error

Tags: javascript, web, jestjs, fs

Before you dislike, leave a comment telling me why...

One of these strings is imported using fs and the other is created through code. I noticed some weird characters when debugging but i'm not sure how to get this to pass without trimming. I don't want to trim since that will ruin a lot of the other checks, spacing matters.

32m vs 31m is the reason these strings aren't matching.

[image]

[image]

More Context:

[image]

Even More Context:

```
  const originalFile = fs.readFileSync(`./tests/mocks/${filePath}.js`, 'utf8');

  const classParser = ClassParser.create();
  let parseResult = classParser.parse(originalFile, '');

  const compiledFile = fs.readFileSync(`./tests/mocks/${filePath}.d.ts`, 'utf8');

  const typeFileAry = parseResult.typeFile.split('\n');
  const compileAry = compiledFile.split('\n');

  expect(typeFileAry.length).toBe(compileAry.length);

  for(let i = 0; i < typeFileAry.length; ++i) {
    expect(typeFileAry[i]).toEqual(compileAry[i]);
  }
```

Dug into Jest Source Code and it looks like they do Object.is(a,b) and that is returning false. Object.is('','') typically returns true. I'm not sure where those characters are coming from.

Comment: Have you tried to create a minimal, reproducible example? I find it can sometimes help to narrow down the root cause and find a solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ShannonMatthews The empty strings is about as narrow as i can get it. It used to be a huge string not being equal but then i split the string on new line to compare every line individually.

Comment: `Object.is('', '')` will always return true. There must be something else going on, like you have a line that has a difference

Answer (score 3):

the "===" operator will return true only if both variables have the same value and **type**. If the value is the same, maybe there is a type mismatch.

To test it, you can check your variable's type using typeof operator.

Check here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Both are strings.

Comment: Also im using expect(string).toBe(string) in Jest.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this today (two seemingly empty strings not being equal). The output from Jest was:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: ""
Received: "​"
```

After converting the string to codepoints (`Array.from(string).map((char) => char.charCodeAt(0))`) it seems that a non-breaking space had crept in from one of the elements I was getting the `innerText` of.

Worth running something like the above to verify there aren't any "hidden" chars that don't appear in your terminal, but exist in the string.